# 100% Heights vs Browser Zoom

Tags: css, drupal, browser, zooming, user-experience

I've looked and there doesn't appear to be another post the is exactly what I am looking for, and I am on a deadline to make this work so lets see if I can explain it better.

We have one page in development on a Drupal site that uses Panels and Views Slideshow. There are a lot of absolute and fixed position elements because of where they need to be on the page. The parent div needs to have a width and height of 100% to fill the page. Keeping in mind that the point of this page is to not have scrollbars and present everything to the user no matter what screen size they are on. So I have media queries cleaning up elements where need be on certain screen sizes.

Though when a user uses their browser to zoom into the page, the elements start shifting and stacking on top of each other. I believe this is because the 100% height/width is adhering specifically to the window size and doesn't expand beyond the window when a user zooms in.

I was able to fix it by removing the 100%'s and replacing them with pixels, but this becomes an issue because if the screen isn't the correct height or width, then you have scrollbars and the user doesn't immediately see everything on the page.

Is there any JavaScript or anything that can utilize the 100% height/width and allow them to expand beyond the page, and turn on scrollbars, during Browser Zoom?

Keep in mind that if a user is zooming in, its OK for the page to spill off and scrollbars to show, but the default screen this is not allowed.

I hope this is OK to show but an example of a page that uses Javascript to scale the entire page is pretty much what I can see myself needing but don't know how.

http://www.ammunitiongroup.com/

Any help appreciated and the quicker the better of course :)

Comment: hmm maybe that link isn't exactly what I want. I do like/want the ability to adjust the height and width of the page based on window but their site doesn't zoom in properly so disregard.

Comment: What browser are you seeing the scrollbars in?

Comment: @BeEasy Not seeing any scrollbars at the moment which is the main issue. If I have set page heights/widths and fixed/absolute elements, then the scrollbars appear during zoom-in. Though with 100% height/widths and fixed/absolute elements, no scrollbars appear and the content either bunches up on the page or spills off and you can't see it. I have been applying overflow:auto where needed with no avail.

Comment: I may have found some headway. If I apply a min-width:px value, then if I zoom in, the scrollbars appear and i can move  left-right, up-down. Though adding a min-widht:px kinda of goes against the whole point of a fluid grid.

Comment: Nope this won't work entirely either. Since I need some of my elements to be fixed, not absolute, those elements grow and stay right where they are on the screen when you zoom. So sure the scrollbars show as you zoom in, but the fixed elements practically cover everything on the page once you zoom in.

Comment: Can you load the page with the parent DIV set to 100%, then change the attributes to px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. Lets you detect the browser zoom level in mordern browsers. 
https://github.com/yonran/detect-zoom

Example page:
http://htmldoodads.appspot.com/dimensions.html